# Perpage footmisc footref workaround

Tags: footnotes, footmisc

Does anyone knows a way to have the same footref in different pages and always showing up per every new page? I am using footmisc package and I have tried it with the perpage option, but nothing seems to work.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[paperwidth=100mm, paperheight=30mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{footmisc}

\begin{document}

Ab omni peccato,\footnote{libera nos, Jesu.\label{libera}}

Ab ira tua,\footref{libera}

\newpage

Ab insidiis diaboli,\footref{libera}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "have the same footref in different pages" and "always showing up per every new page". Thanks.

Comment: Changed the original post to include more complete code and also an image of what is happening.